# ElasticSearch error - curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:9200; Connection refused

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, server

I am trying to install elasticsearch for greylog, I have installed java and inside my elasticSearch.yml file I changed these:

```
cluster.name:graylog
node.name: "node-1"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.bind_host: localhost
network.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
script.inline: false
script.indexed: false
script.file: false
```

All others are comment. But when I run the command

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

I got this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:9200; Connection refused
```

What could be the problem ??

I got this:

```
[2017-06-14 15:37:18,717][ERROR][bootstrap                ] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to created node environment
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:167)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:140)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:143)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:194)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:286)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:45)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: 
/var/lib/elasticsearch/graylog/nodes/0
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
    at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:169)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:165)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you cannot write to the data directory thus the node does not start up.

Do you run this in Docker by any chance and haven't set the right permissions? That's the most common cause of this error.

Comment: Please mark it as the solution if it solved the problem :)

Comment: thanks @xeraa. That was the problem. Change the ownership of /var/lib/elasticsearch and it worked.

Comment: @xeraa: Strangely it worked just once and it fails again. Any idea why it can happen?

Comment: Are you using some orchestration like Openshift that might use different user IDs? With plain Docker I don't think this should be happening. And you only have a single container where the data directory is mounted, right?